# How do I simplify this exponential expression?: $ 2(-3x^{-2}y^3)^{-1} \cdot (-3x^{-3}\cdot y)^2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify this expression?

Simplify:
$$ 2(-3x^{-2}y^3)^{-1} \cdot (-3x^{-3}\cdot y)^2 $$

I tried and didn't get the answer.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: a little remark: $x$ and $y$ have to be different from $0$.

Comment: Good point! $\mathrm{}\\$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Note that $$ \left( ax^p \cdot bx^q \right)^e = \left( ab \cdot x^{p+q} \right)^e = \left( ab \right)^e \cdot x^{e\cdot(p+q)}. $$These are just usages of exponent properties.

**Solution**, here: $$ \begin {align*} 2 \cdot \left( - 3 x^{-2} y^3 \right)^{-1} \cdot \left( -3 x^{-3} y \right)^2 &= 2 \cdot \left( - \dfrac {3y^3}{x^2} \right)^{-1} \cdot \left( - \dfrac {3y}{x^3} \right)^2 \\&= 2 \cdot \left( - \dfrac {x^2}{3y^3} \right) \cdot \left( \dfrac {9y^2}{x^6} \right) \\&= -6 \cdot x^{-4} \cdot y^{-1} = \boxed {-\dfrac {6}{x^4y}}. \end {align*} $$